# Rails 3 and will_paginate - elegant way, how to get total_pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I am working with will_paginate plugin in Rails 3 and I am trying to get to some variable the count of pages (total_pages).

I thought the total pages is in globally variable **@total_pages**, or in @option[:total_pages]**, but if I will use this variables in my view, so it don't work.

I know, I can get the total pages of my items in DB table separately by this plugin, but couldn't be so elegant, if I will have that value already stored in some variable by plugin...

So I would like to ask you - exist any way, how to get this value throw **will_paginate** plugin?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

if you have a posts model,

```
 <%= @posts.total_pages %>
```

will give you the pages total, i.e you need to reference the model you're calling will_paginate on

http://rdoc.info/github/mislav/will_paginate/master/WillPaginate/Collection