# Displaying message on last page with will_paginate gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, will-paginate

Within a simple CRUD rails app, I am using the [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). I've decided to remove the page numbers as well as the previous_link button. I am only rendering the next_link.

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false, :next_label => 'more', :previous_label => '' %>
```

How would I go about displaying a custom message on the last page. Such as "this is the end."

I'm thinking I might have to override some of the methods for will_paginate and put some sort of boolean in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way to implement this is adding some conditions on view:

```
<% prev = (@posts.total_pages == @posts.current_page) ? '' : 'prev' %>
<%= will_paginate @posts, :page_links => false, :next_label => 'more', :previous_label => prev %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Move to app/assets/Stylesheets/application.css have the following css in your file

```
.apple_pagination {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: default; }
  .apple_pagination a, .apple_pagination span {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em; }
  .apple_pagination .disabled {
    color: #aaaaaa; }
  .apple_pagination .current {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #bebebe;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.4em;
    height: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) 1px 1px 1px; }
  .apple_pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black; }
    .apple_pagination a:hover, .apple_pagination a:focus {
      text-decoration: underline; }
```

Move to app/views/index.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @posts ,:class => "apple_pagination"%>
```

You will find the last page number which is an end.

Also in posts_controller.rb

@posts = Post.order("published_at desc").page(params[:page]).per_page(20)

Answer (score 1):

That is a good way @Talgat suggested: check out these answers on here as well:

[will_paginate show the last page by default (keeping chronological order)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291143/will-paginate-show-the-last-page-by-default-keeping-chronological-order)

[will_paginate find out if I'm on the last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699436/will-paginate-find-out-if-im-on-the-last-page)

[Rails 3 and will_paginate - elegant way, how to get total_pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976274/rails-3-and-will-paginate-elegant-way-how-to-get-total-pages)